# Can method references point to an enclosing class?

Tags: java, method-reference

Given:

```
public class Outer
{
    public void hello()
    {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }

    class Inner
    {
        public void world()
        {
            System.out.println("World hello");
        }

        public void run()
        {
            Runnable works = this::world;
            Runnable fails = this::hello;
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to assign `fails` a method reference to `Outer.hello()`?

Comment: Try Outer::this::hello or this::Outer::hello

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos That's the first thing I tried. It results in a compiler error.

Comment: `Outer.this::hello`

Answer (score 4):

It figures... 30 seconds after posting the question I figured it out through trial and error :)

`Runnable fails = Outer.this::hello` will do the job. I didn't expect to have to mix the `.` and `::` operators together, but it seems this works.

Comment: Makes more sence than Outer::this doesn't?